# Почему не срабатывает постфиксный инкремент после выполнения операции?

Tags: java, синтаксис, инкремент, syntax

Почему не срабатывает постфиксный инкремент после выполнения операции?

В теории ведь должно быть: сначала операция (в которой находится операнд с инкрементом), потом выполнение постфиксного инкремента. А в примере, инкремент вообще не сработал, ни до, ни после, от него следа вовсе нет:

```
int i = 5;
i = i++; //Я ожидал, что будет: 5 присваивается в i, только потом выполняется 5+1 в i (в это же переменную, здесь же не j например стоит...).
System.out.println(i); //Вывод: 5... Почему не 6? Инкремент что-то сделал?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Все манипуляции с правой частью происходят **до** выполнения присваивания.

```
int i = 5;

//i = i++; 
int __temp = i; // __temp стало 5
i++; // i стало 6
i = __temp; // i стало 5

System.out.println(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Правило постфиксного инкремента - он возвращает значение аргумента **до инкремента**. Префиксный - значение **после**.

```
int i = 5;
int j = 1 + (i++); // i==6, j==6
```

---

```
int i = 5;
int j = 1 + (++i); // i==6, j==7
```

Возможная реализация на С++ (Java не поддерживает передачу по ссылке):

```
int prefixInc(int& i)
{
  int temp = i;
  i += 1;
  return temp;
}
int postfixInc(int& i)
{
  i += 1;
  int temp = i;
  return temp;
}
```

Comment: Ну вот читаем ваше определение и применяем на моём примере: –i вернул значение 5; –5 присвоено в i; –сработал инкремент (=в i уже 6). Определение не сработало.

Comment: Если присвоение должно быть после всего что справа (как указано в другом ответе), то: –i вернул значение 5; –сработал инкремент, в последнюю очередь, ведь команд в правой части присваивания больше нет (=в i уже 6); –6 присвоено в i (6 потому что i уже 6, хоть с инкрементом, хоть нет). Определение не сработало.

Comment: А вот если сформулировать **работу постфиксного инкремента (типа определение)** следующим образом, то всё сходится: –операнд копируется во временную переменную; –выполняется инкремент; –команда (в которой находиться инкремент) выполняется с временной переменной (т. е. с начальным значением операнда). При этом: в операции присваивания, присваивание выполняется всегда после манипуляций справа.

Comment: Сходиться не только для моего примера, а всегда.